# Missing "ebd" when citing a source twice / custom citation style!

Tags: biblatex

I need help with my latex perferences concerning the cite-style. Ok, I'll start with my minimum example:

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper, % A4 paper size
    12pt, % larger font size
    BCOR = 1cm, % make inner margin (book) larger
    bibtotoc,
]{scrartcl}


\usepackage{scrhack} % addition to koma script; disables warning concerning

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[citestyle=authortitle-ibid, hyperref, backend=bibtex8, style=alphabetic, ibidtracker=context]{biblatex}
\bibliography{literaturverzeichnis}


\DeclareCiteCommand{\footpartcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \mkbibbrackets{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
   \setunit{\addnbspace}
   \printnames{author}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}
   \printfield[citetitle]{title}%
   \newunit
   \printfield{year}}
  {\addsemicolon\space}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\usepackage[
    pdftitle={\doctitle},
    pdfauthor={\docauthor},
    pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black,
    citecolor=black,
    plainpages=false,
    hypertexnames=false,
    pdfpagelabels=true,
    hyperfootnotes=false,
    hyperindex=true 
    ]{hyperref} 


\begin{document}

This is a text taken from source A\footpartcite{firstsource}. A few lines below there's another text taken by source A\footpartcite{firstsource}.

\end{document}
```

This gives me a footnote with the correct citation style and a perfect bibliography the way I want. BUT. When I cite a source two times on a single page, it produces the exact same footnote, instead of "ebd" (that's the german "ibid"). How can I force the \footpartcite command to print "ebd" when citing the same source on the same page? Or do you suggest to use another citation style?

Sorry if I forgot anything to mention. It's my first "minimum example". :)

Comment: You will note that `citestyle=authortitle-ibid, style=alphabetic` is equivalent to the shorter `style=alphabetic`.

Answer (score 1):

We can sneak the "ibid" tests from the `...-ibid` styles into your definition of `\footpartcite`

```
\providecommand*{\mkibid}[1]{#1}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footpartcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
     {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}}
     {\printtext[brackets]{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
      \setunit{\addnbspace}%
      \printnames{labelname}%
      \setunit{\labelnamepunct}%
      \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
      \newunit
      \printfield{labelyear}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Note that I have changed some of the printed fields to more generic versions and added some `%` to avoid spurious space. For `labelyear` you will have to load `biblatex` with the option `lableyear` enabled.

MWE

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper, % A4 paper size
    12pt, % larger font size
    BCOR = 1cm, % make inner margin (book) larger
    bibtotoc,
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrhack} % addition to koma script; disables warning concerning

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8, style=alphabetic, ibidtracker=context, labelyear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\providecommand*{\mkibid}[1]{#1}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footpartcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
     {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}}
     {\printtext[brackets]{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
      \setunit{\addnbspace}%
      \printnames{labelname}%
      \setunit{\labelnamepunct}%
      \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
      \newunit
      \printfield{labelyear}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\usepackage{hyperref} 


\begin{document}
This is a text taken from source A\footpartcite{sigfridsson}. A few lines below there's another text taken by source A\footpartcite{sigfridsson}.
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for you help! I'll implement it as soon as I can.

Comment: @Tommy If this answer helped you, feel free to up-vote and accept it.